# jQuery animating sub-menus on click

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, click, show-hide

I'm trying to put together a navigation menu that uses `click` instead of `hover` to display the sub-menus (or dropdowns).

I have it set up but it's not quite working. I don't know how to close the currently open sub-menu when clicking on another.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu nav-main">

  <li class="nav-about"><a href="#">About us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; ">
      <li><a href="/what-we-do/">What we do</a></li>
      <li><a href="/why-we-do-it/">Why we do it</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-weare"><a href="#">Who we are</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; ">
      <li><a href="/who-we-are/ambassadors/">Ambassadors</a></li>
      <li><a href="/who-we-are/trustees/">Trustees</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-involved"><a href="#">Get involved</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; ">
      <li><a href="/get-involved/coach/">Become a coach</a></li>
      <li><a href="/get-involved/academy/">Become an academy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Currently to get each sub-menu to show and hide I use this jQuery:

```
$('#menu-primary-navigation li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

But the problem is they work independently and go over the top of each other (all can be open at once).

I need a way to detect a click of another top level link that closes any currently open sub-menus and shows the sub-menu for the clicked link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `sub-menu` item that's `visible` and `slideToggle` it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNJNy/)

```
$('#menu-primary-navigation > li > a').click(function(e) {  // select only the child link and not all links, this prevents sub links from being selected. 
    var sub_menu = $(this).next('.sub-menu'); // store the current submenu to be toggled  
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sub-menu:visible').not(sub_menu).slideToggle('fast'); // select all visible sub menus excluding the current one that was clicked on and close them 
    sub_menu.slideToggle('fast'); // toggle the current sub menu 
});
```

Comment: That works nicely apart from if you click the open menu to close it, it closes, then opens itself again.

Comment: Try the new code. I revamped it to account for different situations http://jsfiddle.net/UNJNy/3/

Answer (score 0):

On your sub-menu click events you could add a class 'submenuopen'

```
$(this).addClass('submenuopen')
```

On your parent click events, look for elements that contain that class. Remove the class and hide the elements.